# How to level an old cement floor?

Tags: floor

I have an old garage where I want to make an office. The floor is not 100%  leveled and has some holes. I read about self leveling material for the floor. Is this something one can apply? is it easy? Are there other diy solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Self-leveling material may be appropriate depending on the condition of the existing floor and the depth of the repair. You'd need to take some measurements and read the product literature to know for sure.

The alternate approach is to rip treated joists as needed to create a level frame, then overlay suitable subfloor sheathing.

Without more information that's about as specific as I can get.

Answer (score 1):

I used self-leveling product for my basement, and yes it is doable for your typical FIT DIYer, but it is best with two people if you have to mix more than a couple of bags. It is actually a quite demanding task as each 50 pound bag must be mixed and poured and worked in before it dries.  Each of these bags must be mixed with a powerful drill. In my basement I had to use ~12 -  50 pound bags, and I was exhausted after the hour or so it took to apply them. My wife helped for the 1st 8 bags but got exhausted and I had to finish myself. The best tip I can give is to watch a some youtube videos on how to apply the material. In the end I was very happy with my results and I was able to apply laminate flooring to the level surface.

Answer (score 0):

you can level any floor with self leveling mortars, but they have to be the right ones.  the typical ones you find at big box stores are overpriced garbage.  here is the one we use:

http://flextile.net/products/CIS/p-cisSP-59.html

just check their site for installation and youtube for how it works.